# Derive formula for conformal curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

So I'm working through Needham's Visual Differential Geometry and Forms, and what is suggested as a simple exercise is to reduce the general Gaussian curvature formula

$$K = -\frac{1}{AB}\left(\partial_{v}\frac{\partial_{v}A}{B} + \partial_{u}\frac{\partial_{u}B}{A}\right)$$

to

$$K = -\frac{\nabla^2ln\Lambda}{\Lambda^2}$$

when the metric is conformal, i.e.

$$ds^2 = \Lambda^2(du^2 + dv^2)$$

(Pages 40-41.  Note, Needham uses $A^2 = E$, $B^2 = F$ in his version of the general curvature, compared to the more common formulation.)  I'm sure it is simple but I am just not seeing it.  Obviously, we can immediately get

$$K = -\frac{1}{\Lambda^2}\left(\partial_{v}\frac{\partial_{v}\Lambda}{\Lambda} + \partial_{u}\frac{\partial_{u}\Lambda}{\Lambda}\right)$$

with the obvious substitution, but I have no idea where to take it from there, and in particular no idea where the $ln$ would come from.  I'm understanding that $\Lambda$ depends on $u, v$ essentially arbitrarily, is that my error somehow?  But if it is a constant then $K$ collapses to $0$, so I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ remind you of $(\ln f)'(x)$? This is all that's going on, but with partial derivatives.

Comment: OMG.... thank you

Comment: You’re welcome. :)